# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

```
[I try to make Twitter Bot but always become this Error Can anyone Help! thank you!][1]
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQdOU.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"\Users\3shal\OneDrive\Desktop\twitterbot\chromedriver")
driver.get("https:twitter.com/")
sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]').send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_name('session[password]').send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_name('session[password]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(5)


f = open("contant.txt", 'r')

for word in f:
if word == "\n":
    continue
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data=testid='SideNav_NewTweet_Button']").click()


sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("notranslate").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("notranslate").send_keys(word)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data=testid='tweetButton']").click()
sleep(5)

f.close()
```

try to make Twitter Bot but always become this Error and yes i checked the chrome version and updated everything
Can anyone Help! thank you!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@data=testid='SideNav_NewTweet_Button']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have small typo in your xpath.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='tweetButton']").click()
```

It not `data=testid`, it's `data-testid`. Fixing this should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you very much  i have one last problem,      driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='tweetButton']").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'             
 the last .click() dose not work like others i mean as a webElement

Comment: @Adam Replace `find_elements*` with `find_element*` you will be good to go.

Comment: this is so embarrassing hahahah thank you @DebanjanB